# How to convert variables of a list into separate lists

Tags: python, list, binary

I would like to convert the list that I have into separate lists

What I have : `x = ['0b1001000', '0b1100101', '0b1101100', '0b1101100', '0b1101111']`

What I want :

```
x1 = ['0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0']
x2 = ['0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1'] 
x3 = ['0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0']
x4 = ['0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0'] 
x5 = ['0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1']
```

Comment: What have you tried? can you show your code attempt for this, please? Explain what is currently not working out for you. Show any error messages, if any.

Comment: Also, if you are dealing with an n-size list, I would suggest using a dictionary for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @idjaw I didn't have any, I simply didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

My be this:

```
>> [list(filter(str.isdigit, ele)) for ele in x]
[['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1'], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0'], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0'], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['0b1001000', '0b1100101', '0b1101100', '0b1101100', '0b1101111']
for each in x:
    k = filter(str.isdigit,each)
    print list(k)
```